Error on the square of sum of binary elements for symbolic upper limit
I'm seeing the following error: as a part of some equations, I have $E[(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2]$, with $X_i\sim Ber(p)$. Using independence between $X_i$ and $X_j$ for $i\ne j$ and that $X_i^2=X_i$, $E[(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2] = E[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i] + E[\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n X_iX_j] = np + n(n-1)p^2$.
The problem is that it's not the solution that Mathematica is returning. I have the following code:
x[i_] := Subscript[x, i];

rule1 = {x[i_]^2 -> x[i]}; 
rule2 = {x[i_] -> p};

expr = Expand[(Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}])^2];
Simplify[expr /. rule1 /. rule2]

Where the expr is $(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2$, and then use rule1 to convert x[i_]^2 -> x[i] as $X_i$ is binary. Finally, to compute the expectation, I do x[i_] -> p.
After computing the code, I get n^2p^2, which is not correct. Something more strange is that if I compute
expr = Expand[(Sum[x[i], {i, 1, 10}])^2];
Simplify[expr /. rule1 /. rule2]

where I changed n for 10 in the expression, I get the correct answer that is 10p(1+9p) (for any other fixed number it still returns the correct answer).
Why is Mathematica not handling the sum with a symbolic upper limit correctly, even though it works for fixed integers? Is there any way to solve this with a solution that can be generalized so I can compute $E[(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^k]$ for an arbitrary $k$?

Mathematica is not sympy nor sagemath. Hence, all letters are symbols by default. So no need to do n = Symbol["n"];

Are you saying that  Sum[p, {i, 1, n}]^2 should not give n^2*p^2 ?

What you wrote is correct, but not what I'm calculating. First we would have to expand the squared sum of $X_i$ and then, after taking into account that $X_i^2=X_i$, take the expectation to arrive to $E[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i] + E[\sum_{i\neq j} X_i X_j] = np+n(n-1)p^2$.

but not what I'm calculating. I do not know what you are calculating. I am just running the code you posted. Please post complete code you are using in this case.

I'm calculating $E[(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2]$. I know that the answer is $np+n(n-1)p^2$, but according to Mathematica the answer is $n^2p^2$ when considering $n$ as symbolic. The code I'm using is the one I pasted, where first I expand (Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}])^2, then apply the substitution given by the rule 1 so x[i_]^2 -> x[i] and finally x[i_] -> p that would be computing the expectation.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm calculating Then update your question and post the exact code you typed. You typed  Expand[....]  but you say you wanted expectation. Expand is not the the expectation command.

Take a look at expr = Expand[(Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}])^2] (i.e., remove the semicolon).  You'll see that Expand isn't doing what you think it's doing.  Mathematica will give the correct answers for specified values of n using the functions you've chosen.  But if you want results for a general positive integer n, you'll need to use other Mathematica functions.  I'll put together an answer.

I know that Expand[...] is not the expectation. To calculate the expectation I'm using that $E[X_i]$ is $p$, the linearity of the expectation and the fact that $X_i$ never appears on a degree higher than 1. So after applying rule1 I can just replace $X_i$ with $p$ (that would be equivalent as taking the expectation on this case). So maybe I'm not clear, but Expand is doing exactly what I want (although I don't know if it's necessary), and I'm taking the expectation on rule2

If you're temporarily willing to specify values for $n$ and $k$, then the following will work:  parms = {k -> 2, n -> 7}; (Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}]^k /. parms // Expand) /. {x[i_]^j_ -> p,   x[i_] -> p}.  I'll work on an answer for general $n$ (and maybe $k$) a bit later.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

exp[n_Integer?Positive] := exp[n] =
  Mean[TransformedDistribution[Sum[x[k], {k, 1, n}]^2, 
    x[#] \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[p] & /@ Range[n]]]

sol[n_, p_] = FindSequenceFunction[exp /@ Range[5], n] // Simplify

(* n p (1 + (-1 + n) p) *)

Checking beyond original sequence,
And @@ Table[exp[n] == sol[n, p], {n, 1, 20}]

(* True *)

EDIT: Using your approach
rule1 = {x[i_]^2 -> x[i]};
rule2 = {x[i_] -> p};

expr[n_Integer?Positive] := expr[n] = Expand[Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}]^2];

seq2 = Simplify[expr[#] /. rule1 /. rule2] & /@ Range[5]

(* {p, 2 p (1 + p), 3 p (1 + 2 p), 4 p (1 + 3 p), 5 p (1 + 4 p)} *)

sol2[n_, p_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq2, n] // Simplify

(* n p (1 + (-1 + n) p) *)

sol[n, p] === sol2[n, p]

(* True *)


Thanks! the use of FindSequenceFunction is what I needed, in particular for more complex sums :)

Here are two ways where you don't have to specify $n$ (but you do have to specify $k$).
First, the sum of $n$ independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables has a binomial distribution so the raw moments of the sum can be found with
k=2
Moment[BinomialDistribution[n, p], k]
(* n p - (1 - n) n p^2 *)

Second, using the fact that you mention ($X_i^k=X_i$), one can do the following:
k = 2;
MomentConvert[PowerSymmetricPolynomial[1]^k, 
  "AugmentedSymmetricPolynomial"] /. {AugmentedSymmetricPolynomial[z_] :> 
  Length[z]! Binomial[n, Length[z]] p^Length[z]}
(* n p + (-1 + n) n p^2 *)

Update
From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution here is the general formula where you don't have to give specific positive integers for $n$ or $k$:
Sum[StirlingS2[k, i] FactorialPower[n, i] p^i, {i, 1, k}] // FunctionExpand

